# \textwidth does change its value inside list

Tags: indentation, tabto

If I understood it right, `\textwidth` should not change its value inside lists. But if I do the following, the indentation is not the same inside and outside of the list:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Test \tabto{0.5\textwidth} Test
\end{itemize}
\tabto{0.5\textwidth} Test

\end{document}
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You're doing nothing wrong: the point where the tabbing starts is different in the two cases; inside a list it's shifted right by `\leftmargin`.

Comment: It is not clear what you want to achieve looking at the documentation, `\tabto` just moves you a fixed length from the left edge of the paragraph, and since you have moved in by the same amount in each case the first one is further to the right by the amount of the list indentation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're doing nothing wrong. You're just not considering where `\tabto` starts from: it starts from the current left margin, which is shifted right in a list.

Since the amount of shifting is always known and stored in the parameter `\@totalleftmargin`, you can define a macro that takes care of this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabto}

\makeatletter % we need to access a command with @ in its name
\newcommand\xtabto[1]{%
  \tabto{\dimexpr#1-\@totalleftmargin\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Test \xtabto{0.5\textwidth} Test
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Test \xtabto{0.5\textwidth} Test
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\xtabto{0.5\textwidth} Test

\end{document}
```

You see that this works also in second level list environments. You can use `\xtabto` or `\tabto` interchangeably *outside* list environments; but it's probably wiser sticking to only one command throughout.

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I missunderstood the `\tabto` command. I expected that it would jump to the given position, like a tabstop in word. Thanks for the macro which does this!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tabto}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Test \tabto{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-\labelwidth-\labelsep} Test
\end{itemize}
\tabto{0.5\textwidth} Test

\end{document}
```